# Removing all embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to remove all embedded documents from a collection, but I can't figure out how to do that.

I have tried a few ways, but I think this one should work:

```
Products.update({_id: data._id}, { $pull : { orders : {$gte: 0} } });
```

Products is the collection, orders is the array with embedded documents.

Remove all `orders` where the index is greater or equal than 0.

No luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
db.products.update({_id: data._id},
                   {$unset: {orders: 1}})
```

or this

```
db.products.update({_id: data._id},
                   {$set: {orders: []}})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers. I did not downvote this, I do not know who did this. I will try the methods tho, and give a +1;

Comment: I don't see a downvote, but you're welcome to give your upvote (and accept) if it works :)

Comment: wow, strangly neither of the two work, and I think I had tried them both already. THe id part is correct, I can find the correct product, and I can console.log the orders array. But neither set or unset do the trick. Could is be that the collection is locked somehow. Or do I need to save after the update?

Comment: @SaifBechan: it definitely should work. See here: http://pastebin.com/BuFnCPrF Are you trying in the db shell?

Comment: How extremely annoying. Well thanks for confirming that this should work. Will try and find out where my problem lies.

Comment: If you do find it, let us know :)